# createServer does not show responses

Tags: javascript, node.js

as shown in the code posted below, i am creating a server using `createServer`. i would like to test it.therefore, in the browser, i entered the following urls:

```
http://localhost:3000/
http://localhost:3000/hello
```

i expected to receive the text stated in the first `if-condition` as the former url is `/` and
i expected to receive the text stated in the second `if-condition` as the latter url is `/hello`

but none of the aforementioned cases occurred.
would you please recify my understanding and tell me why the web-browser shows no responses?

**code**:

```
const options = {
keepAlive:true,
}
const functionListener = (req,res)=>{
    console.log("headerSent:",res.headersSent())
    console.log("statusCode :",res.statusCode ())
    if (req.url == '/') {
        res.writeHead(200, "succeeded",{ 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
        // set response content    
        res.write('<html><body><p>This is default Page.</p></body></html>');
        res.end(JSON.stringify({
            data: 'default!',
          }));
    }

    if (req.url == '/hello') {
        res.writeHead(200, "succeeded",{ 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
        // set response content    
        res.write('<html><body><p>This is hello Page.</p></body></html>');
        res.end(JSON.stringify({
            data: 'Hello World!',
          }));
    }
}
const server = http.createServer(options,functionListener => {

});
server.listen(port)
```

Comment: Instead of passing the handler function, you are currently passing an empty arrow function. Remove `=> {}`.

Comment: Also you can't return different responses at once, that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @CherryDT would you please tell me where i am sending multiple responses? do you mean the `.writeHead` and `.write`?

Comment: You also have `.end` with a different type of response, JSON ^^

Comment: @CherryDT would you please tell me why it is bad practice to use different types of responses JSON and HTML?

Comment: It's not just bad practice, it's just not making sense. A browser would show you JSON data at the end of the page and see invalid HTML, and an application expecting JSON would see invalid JSON at the start (that's actually HTML). In fact you made it even more confusing because you declare the whole response to be plain text, neither HTML nor JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with change this:

```
const server = http.createServer(options,functionListener => {

});
```

to this:

```
const server = http.createServer(options, functionListener);
```

Your first version is just passing an empty arrow function as the argument that happens to have its first argument named `functionListener` which has no connection at all to the function you defined by that same name.

The fixed version passes a reference to the `functionListener` function you defined so that `http.createServer()` can call that function as desired.

Then, it doesn't make sense that you're sending BOTH an HTML response and a JSON response.  Pick one or the other and set the `content-type` to match.

Comment: thanks,the last point you mentioned is not clear to me, the one which is about HTML-content and content-type..would you please provide an example

Comment: @LetsamrIt - Your response should either be HTML (text/html) or JSON (application/json), not BOTH.  While you can send both and just label it as `text/plain`, that's not likely useful to the client as the content-type does not describe the format of the data in a way that would be useful to the client.